# Concatenation Coincidence

Tags: code-golf, sequence, number-theory

This [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge (and test cases) are inspired by the work of Project Euler users amagri, Cees.Duivenvoorde, and oozk, and Project Euler Problem 751. (And no, this isn't on OEIS). [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/23997/82007)

A non-decreasing sequence of integers \$a_n\$ can be generated from any positive real value \$\theta\$ by the following procedure:

$$
\newcommand{\flr}[1]{\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor}
\begin{align}
b_n & = 
\begin{cases}
\theta, & n = 1 \\
\flr {b_{n-1}} (b_{n-1} - \flr{b_{n-1}} + 1), & n \ge 2
\end{cases} \\
a_n & = \flr{b_n}
\end{align}
$$

Where \$\flr x\$ is the floor function.

For example, \$\theta=2.956938891377988...\$ generates the Fibonacci sequence: 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...

The *concatenation* of a sequence of positive integers \$a_n\$ is a real value denoted \$τ\$ constructed by concatenating the elements of the sequence after the decimal point, starting at \$a_1\$: $$\tau = a_1.a_2a_3a_4...$$

For example, the Fibonacci sequence constructed from \$\theta=2.956938891377988...\$ yields the concatenation \$τ=2.3581321345589...\$ Clearly, \$τ ≠ \theta\$ for this value of \$\theta\$.

We call a positive real number \$\theta\$ **coincidental** if \$\theta = τ\$ as generated above.

## Challenge

Given a natural number \$k > 0\$ as input, you must output the number of coincidental numbers \$\theta\$ such that \$k = \flr \theta\$.

## Test Cases

```
1   -> 1
2   -> 1
3   -> 0
4   -> 2
5   -> 1
6   -> 0
7   -> 0
8   -> 0
9   -> 0
10  -> 1
11  -> 1
12  -> 1
13  -> 1
14  -> 1
15  -> 1
16  -> 2
17  -> 1
18  -> 1
19  -> 1
20  -> 2
21  -> 2
22  -> 1
23  -> 1
24  -> 1
25  -> 1
26  -> 1
27  -> 2
28  -> 2
29  -> 1
30  -> 2
31  -> 2
32  -> 1
33  -> 0
34  -> 1
35  -> 1
36  -> 3
37  -> 0
38  -> 2
39  -> 3
40  -> 1
41  -> 1
42  -> 1
43  -> 4
44  -> 3
45  -> 1
46  -> 1
47  -> 2
48  -> 2
49  -> 4
50  -> 1
```

Comment: Ok. Sorry, I used to be a whiz at all things math, but that has been more than 20 years ago. It's all those danged ecommerce sites, I tell ya. I got into software to solve puzzles, not to building shopping carts.:) Seriously, though, thank you. I am deleting my first question now out of respect and to keep the playing field clean. I will delete this as well in a bit. Happy coding.

Comment: Seriously, brute force cannot be the only solution to this. There has to be some pattern or rule here to build the numbers and I will find it dammit. I think I'm getting close too. Great puzzle btw. Love this sort of stuff.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 33 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
žhтã'.ì«ʒтsλ£Dï©->®*}ïć'.«šJyÅ?}g
```

Brute-force, so extremely slow. The program above validates all real values \$\theta\$ in the range \$[input,input+1)\$ in increments of \$10^{-100}\$. Replacing the two `т` above with `4` and `5` respectively (to make the increments of size \$10^{-4}\$) at least gives outputs, although does still fail for some of the test cases unfortunately<sup>*†*</sup>:
[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ATwAw/9vc2FiaWX//8W@aDTDoycuw6zCq8qSNXPOu8KjRMOvwqktPsKuKn3Dr8SHJy7Cq8WhSnnDhT99Z///MTY)

<sup>*†*: the failing test cases when we use `4` & `5` are: \$k=21\$ (requires at least `9` & `6`); \$k=29\$ (requires at least `5` & `4`); \$k=33\$ (requires at least `5` & `4`); \$k=36\$ (requires at least `6` & `4`); \$k=37\$ (requires at least `5` & `4`); \$k=39\$ (requires at least `5` & `4`); \$k=40\$ (requires at least `5` & `4`); \$k=43\$ (requires at least `7` & `5`); \$k=44\$ (requires at least `5` & `4`);  and \$k=49\$ (requires at least `5` & `4`).</sup>

**Explanation:**

```python
žh                     # Push builtin 0123456789
  тã                   # Cartesian power of 100: create all possible strings of size 100
                       # using these digits
    '.ì               '# Prepend a "." in front of each
       «               # Merge each to the (implicit) input-integer
                       # (we now have a list of decimal values in the range
                       # [input,input+1) in increments of 1e-100)
        ʒ              # Filter this list of real values `θ` by:
           λ           #  Start a recursive environment,
         т  £          #  to output the first 100 values
          s            #  Where a(0)=`θ`
                       #  and where every following a(n) is calculated as follows:
                       #   (Implicitly push a(n-1))
             D         #   Duplicate this a(n-1)
              ï        #   Floor it
               ©       #   Store this floored a(n-1) in variable `®` (without popping)
                -      #   Subtract it from a(n-1)
                 >     #   Increase it by 1
                  ®*   #   Multiply it by `®`
           }ï          #  After the recursive method: floor all values in the list
             ć         #  Extract the head (the floored value we started with; a.k.a. the
                       #  input); pop and push remainder-list and first item separated to
                       #  the stack
              '.«     '#  Append a "."
                 š     #  Prepend it back to the list
                  J    #  Join this list together to a string
                   yÅ? #  Check if it starts with the current `θ` as prefix
        }g             # After the filter: pop and push the length
                       # (which is output implicitly as result)
```